# How to pass on every country name to dictionary's keys using api?(python)

Tags: python, json

trying to use an API to fill a dictionary's keys with every country's name. I will fill in the values. Trying to save time as opposed to typing in every country manually.
Here is a link with countries https://www.dfa.ie/travel/travel-advice/a-z-list-of-countries/

The format I have currently is below..

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://www.dfa.ie/travel/travel-advice/a-z-list-of-countries/")

print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```

Comment: what have you tried? the code shown is checking for a valid http response from that site, it doesn't help with API endpoints in that sense.

Comment: You could use beautifoulsoup to parse the website OR you could simply copy the list of countries to your clipboard and simply save that to a text file. You just need to parse that file.

Comment: sorry, that was a check for the website actually working.. I need to know how to implement the parameters following the url to send off names of countries to my keys according to my research.

Comment: this should help ya, see [link](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Comment: Do you have to use _that_ web page? There are libraries that will give you a list of countries in an easy to use format, such as https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, the URL returns an HTML document and not a JSON object. I suggest using another api endpoint which returns a json object which you can use in Python directly, without going through scraping and all.

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
print(response.status_code)
all_ = response.json()
```

Here `all_` contains an array of all countries with features such as name, capital, topleveldomain, borders, timezone, and many more.
You can use a for loop to access each country in the list and then access it's name and other data if required. then store it to your dictionary.

The API endpoint documentation: https://restcountries.eu/#api-endpoints-all

You can use dictionary comprehension for this purpose:

`my_countries = {x['name']: "your intended values" for x in all_}`

You can put your values in place of `"your intended values"`. It could also be another python object, dict, list, or any other type. `my_countries` will be your resultant dict.

Comment: Thanks so much, however, I tried this site & got a 404 which means the endpoint is inaccessible. I have found a solution.

Comment: Sorry! It's now reading.. I'm fairly new to using API's.. How can I place those country names directly to my keys in dictionary? I understand I need the for loop, but what is the variable I need to address to just get the country name feature? Or if it is a quick solution can you implement it, so I can see the technique you used and study it so I will not come across this issue again?

Comment: You want to store the country name as a key in a dictionary right?

Comment: You can use dictionary comprehension for this purpose: `my_countries = {x['name']: "your intended values" for x in all_}`. You can put your values in place of `"your intended values"`. It could also be another python object, dict, list, or any other type. `my_countries` will be your resultant dict...

Comment: the above code should work. Just add your own values instead of `"your intended values"`. Also, if it is working could you remove the downvote...?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to make it easier to parse the HTML. If you use requests alone, there's alot of string parsing to be done just to get the country names. Here's an example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment, NavigableString

response = requests.get("https://www.dfa.ie/travel/travel-advice/a-z-list-of-countries/")

# Parse response html
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Div containing countries
countries_div = soup.find("div", {"id": "countriesbox"})

# UL list from webpage
list = countries_div.div.ul

# Dictionary to contain all the countries
countries_dict = {}

# Loop through each country element
for country in list:
  if isinstance(country, Comment) or isinstance(country, NavigableString):
    continue

  # Get the country name
  country_name = country.select('a')[0].text

  countries_dict[country_name] = 'some-value'  # Add some value of your choice


# countries_dict variable now contains all the country names as keys
```

[Here's a live demo](https://repl.it/repls/WarlikeLongtermGlobalarrays)